# Doesn't get robots /scan events in ROS

Tags: c++, ros, robotics

I'm trying to get robot /scan events notification.
It works for me:

```
// Subscribe to the simulated robot's laser scan topic
laserSub = nh.subscribe("/scan", 1, &MyObject::scanCallback, this);
```

But when I change the topic to my_robot_name/scan, it doesn't work: I don't get any robot scan notification to my callback.

```
// Subscribe to the simulated robot's laser scan topic
laserSub = nh.subscribe(my_robot_name + "/scan", 1, &MyObject::scanCallback, this);
```

I run "rostopic info my_robot_name/scan", and it looks that no publisher to my_robot_name/scan at all.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on you saying than no one publishes to the topic, it is no wonder that you don't get any messages. If you want to get the messages you need firstly to publish the message.

The problem you are having is that `/scan` is a topic in the **global namespace** (prefix `/`). To publish it to the desired namespace you can change it in the publisher:

- publish to the desired namespace `ros::Publisher publisher = n.advertise<topic>("my_robot_name/scan", 1);`
- use a [group](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/group) in the launch file

If you don't have any influence on the publisher you can use [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) and remap it to the desired topic:

```
<node ...start your node...>
    <remap from="/scan" to="my_robot_name/scan" />
</node>
```

this way `my_robot_name/scan` topic will be available for your callback in the node.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use "remap", as you suggested but it still doesn't work. I still have no publisher to "my_robot_name/scan" but only to "/scan". Subscriber I have in both cases. Here is my updated launch file and my definitions: https://pastebin.com/JQzGVAAs . Do you know what the problem is? Thank you @maetulj

Comment: @Ofir I think I made a mistake there. Try to swap `from` and `to` topics. I always forget which one is which :)